# HERE API - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm trying to set up an Isoline on a map using the calculateisoline method of the HERE API but i keep getting following Error:

[timeout] http://route.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateisoline.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.15.0&app_id=KnNGic2KizTPB2mYGZy0&app_code=48Ound-jjgkPZXAHn2H1bw&mode=fastest%3Bcar&start=geo!52.5%2C13.4&time=PT0H15M request failed

The Code I'm using, which by the way is the original example from the documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 600px" id="mapContainer" align="center"></div>
    <script>
        // Instantiate a map and platform object:
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'app_id': 'APPID',
            'app_code': 'APPCODE'
        });
        // Retrieve the target element for the map:
        var targetElement = document.getElementById('mapContainer');
        // Get the default map types from the platform object:
        var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        // Instantiate the map:
        var map = new H.Map(
                document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
                defaultLayers.normal.map,
                {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: {lat: 52.5159, lng: 13.3777}
                });
        // Create the parameters for the routing request:
        var routingParams = {
            'mode': 'fastest;car',
            'start': 'geo!52.5,13.4',
            'time': 'PT0H15M'
        };
        // Define a callback function to process the isoline response.
        var onResult = function (result) {
            var center = new H.geo.Point(
                    result.Response.Center.Latitude,
                    result.Response.Center.Longitude),
                    isolineCoords = result.Response.isolines[0].value,
                    strip = new H.geo.Strip(),
                    isolinePolygon,
                    isolineCenter;
// Add the returned isoline coordinates to a strip:
            isolineCoords.forEach(function (coords) {
                strip.pushLatLngAlt.apply(strip, coords.split(','));
            });
 // Create a polygon and a marker representing the isoline:
            isolinePolygon = new H.map.Polygon(strip);
            isolineCenter = new H.map.Marker(center);
 // Add the polygon and marker to the map:
            map.addObjects([isolineCenter, isolinePolygon]);
 // Center and zoom the map so that the whole isoline polygon is
 // in the viewport:
             map.setViewBounds(isolinePolygon.getBounds());
        };
 // Get an instance of the enterprise routing service:
        var enterpriseRouter = platform.getEnterpriseRoutingService();
 // Call the Enterprise Routing API to calculate an isoline:
        enterpriseRouter.calculateIsoline(
                routingParams,
                onResult,
                function (error) {
                    alert(error.message);
                });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old URL. URL with `nokia` isn't supported anymore. https://developer.here.com/news/20160217#.WXjlKNOGOqR
You need either update js library or change URL, if it's possible.